# How to convert comma separated NVARCHAR to table records in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a list of ids separated by comma like:

```
 1,17,25,44,46,67,88
```

I want to convert them to a table records ( into a temporary table ) like

```
#tempTable

number_
--------
1
17
25
44
46
67
88
```

It is possible with a **function**, a table-valued one ?

Why I want this ? I want to use for `INNER JOIN` clause (into stored procedure) with another table(s) like as:

```
SELECT a,b,c FROM T1
INNER JOIN functionNameWhichReturnsTable 
ON functionNameWhichReturnsTable.number_ = T1.a
```

I cannot use `IN` because I will use stored procedure which accepts a parameter of type NVARCHAR. That parameter will provide the list of ids.

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split string in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/split-string-in-sql)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Possible duplicate of [separate comma separated values and store in table in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811316/separate-comma-separated-values-and-store-in-table-in-sql-server).

Please try a precise one from [Comma-Delimited Value to Table](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/functions/comma-delimited-to-table.aspx):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_CSVToTable] ( @StringInput VARCHAR(8000), @Delimiter nvarchar(1))
RETURNS @OutputTable TABLE ( [String] VARCHAR(10) )
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @String    VARCHAR(10)

    WHILE LEN(@StringInput) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @String      = LEFT(@StringInput, 
                                ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @StringInput) - 1, -1),
                                LEN(@StringInput)))
        SET @StringInput = SUBSTRING(@StringInput,
                                     ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @StringInput), 0),
                                     LEN(@StringInput)) + 1, LEN(@StringInput))

        INSERT INTO @OutputTable ( [String] )
        VALUES ( @String )
    END

    RETURN
END
GO
```

Check the requirement in other way using XML:

```
DECLARE @param NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @param = '1:0,2:1,3:1,4:0'

SELECT 
     Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS CVS  
FROM  
(
    SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(@param, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS CVS 
) AS A CROSS APPLY CVS.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
```

Comment: The XML split is more than 3 times slower than the loop one!

Comment: XML split will be more faster then loop one if you have thousands of values in a comma separated string i.e. in @param

Comment: To handle spaces in list, e.g. 1, 2, 3, modify section to `SET @String      = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@StringInput, 
                                ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @StringInput) - 1, -1),
                                LEN(@StringInput)))))`

Comment: ufn_CSVToTable works fine only for such string 1,3,5,7,33,22 but we try such strings like 'K2SQL:K2Admin,K2SQL:K2Admin' then its output does not work

Comment: the method which is written here that is working fine in all cases.
https://www.sqlshack.com/converting-commas-or-other-delimiters-to-a-table-or-list-in-sql-server-using-t-sql/

Answer (score 7):

Here's a trick that doesn't need a function or XML.

Basically the string gets transformed into a single insert statement for a temporary table.

The temp table can then be used for further processing.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpNum') IS NOT NULL
      DROP TABLE #tmpNum;

CREATE TABLE #tmpNum (num int);

DECLARE @TEXT varchar(max) = '1,17,25,44,46,67,88';

DECLARE @InsertStatement varchar(max);
SET  @InsertStatement = 'insert into #tmpNum (num) values ('+REPLACE(@TEXT,',','),(')+');';
EXEC (@InsertStatement);

-- use the temp table 
SELECT * 
FROM YourTable t
WHERE t.id IN (SELECT DISTINCT num FROM #tmpNum);
```

This method is usable for up to 1000 values.
Because 1000 is the max limit of a row value expression.

Also, as Stuart Ainsworth pointed out.
Since this method uses Dynamic Sql, be wary of code injection and don't use it for strings based on user input.

**Side-note**

Starting from MS Sql Server 2016, one could simply use the [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) function.

```
DECLARE @TEXT varchar(max);
SET @TEXT = '1,17,25,44,46,67,88';

SELECT t.* 
FROM YourTable t
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT CAST(value AS INT) num FROM STRING_SPLIT(@TEXT, ',')) nums
  ON t.id = nums.num;
```

Comment: Try this line :

DECLARE @TEXT varchar(max) = '1,17,25,44,46,67,88);DELETE FROM #tempTable WHERE (1=1';

SQL injection is possible with this method, though not likely.

Comment: I'm sorry; I think you misunderstood.  I put a DELETE statement into a text string, which would be executed by your exec statement.  THat's a classic form of SQL injection; with sufficient privilege, someone could do all kinds of mischief (like drop a database, create users)...

Comment: Again, it's not likely, but this is a design pattern to avoid.

Comment: Yes, I agree that when you use EXEC that code injection is a considerable risk. But only when you use it with user input. Which isn't always the case. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Well, to be honest, you can't use dynamic SQL with a user function, either (the crux of the original question) :)

Answer (score 0):

Completing the answers, you could also use the CSV string to store multiple values in multiple columns:

```
 --input sql text 
declare @text_IN varchar(max) ='text1, text1.2, text1.3, 1, 2010-01-01\r\n text2, text2.2, text2.3, 2, 2016-01-01'
```

Split the csv file into rows:

```
declare @temptable table (csvRow varchar(max))    
declare @DelimiterInit varchar(4) = '\r\n'
declare @Delimiter varchar(1) = '|'
declare @idx int       
declare @slice varchar(max)    

set @text_IN = REPLACE(@text_IN,@DelimiterInit,@Delimiter)


select @idx = 1       
    if len(@text_IN)<1 or @text_IN is null  return       

while @idx!= 0       
begin       
    set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@text_IN)       
    if @idx!=0       
        set @slice = left(@text_IN,@idx - 1)       
    else       
        set @slice = @text_IN 

    if(len(@slice)>0)  
        insert into @temptable(csvRow) values(@slice)       

    set @text_IN = right(@text_IN,len(@text_IN) - @idx)       
    if len(@text_IN) = 0 break       
end
```

Split rows into columns:

```
;WITH XMLTable (xmlTag)
AS
(
    SELECT CONVERT(XML,'<CSV><champ>' + REPLACE(csvRow,',', '</champ><champ>') + '</champ></CSV>') AS xmlTag
    FROM @temptable
)

 SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(xmlTag.value('/CSV[1]/champ[1]','varchar(max)'))) AS Column1,    
        RTRIM(LTRIM(xmlTag.value('/CSV[1]/champ[2]','varchar(max)'))) AS Column2,
        RTRIM(LTRIM(xmlTag.value('/CSV[1]/champ[3]','varchar(max)'))) AS Column3,    
        RTRIM(LTRIM(xmlTag.value('/CSV[1]/champ[4]','int'))) AS Column4,
        RTRIM(LTRIM(xmlTag.value('/CSV[1]/champ[5]','datetime'))) AS Column5
 FROM XMLTable
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
declare @parStoreNo As varchar(8000) = '1,2,3,4'        
CREATE TABLE #parStoreNo (StoreNo INT)-- drop #parStoreNo
declare @temptable VARCHAR(1000) = @parStoreNo
declare @SQL VARCHAR(1000) 
SELECT @SQL = CONVERT(VARCHAR(1000),' select ' + REPLACE(ISNULL(@temptable,' NULL '),',', ' AS Col UNION ALL SELECT ')) 
INSERT #parStoreNo (StoreNo)
EXEC (@SQL)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using XML Function as below...

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(4000) = '6,7,7,8,10,12,13,14,16,44,46,47,394,396,417,488,714,717,718,719,722,725,811,818,832,833,836,837,846,913,914,919,922,923,924,925,926,927,927,928,929,929,930,931,932,934,935,1029,1072,1187,1188,1192,1196,1197,1199,1199,1199,1199,1200,1201,1202,1203,1204,1205,1206,1207,1208,1209,1366,1367,1387,1388,1666,1759,1870,2042,2045,2163,2261,2374,2445,2550,2676,2879,2880,2881,2892,2893,2894'

Declare @x XML 

select @x = cast('<A>'+ replace(@str,',','</A><A>')+ '</A>' as xml)

select t.value('.', 'int') as inVal
from @x.nodes('/A') as x(t)
```

I prefer this because not need to create any separate function and proc. Also I don't have to opt dynamic SQL query which I prefer most.
[Convert Comma Separated String to Table](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/amitjet/2009/12/11/convert-comma-separated-string-to-table-4-different-approaches/)

Answer (score 0):

```sql
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(4000) = '6,7,7,8,10,12,13,14,16,44,46,47,394,396,417,488,714,717,718,719,722,725,811,818,832'

DECLARE @x XML 
select @x = cast('<A>'+ replace(@str,',','</A><A>')+ '</A>' as xml)

select t.value('.', 'int') as inVal
from @x.nodes('/A') as x(t)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
 SELECT RTRIM(part) as part
    INTO Table_Name
        FROM dbo.splitstring(@Your_Comma_string,',')
```

splitstring Function is as follows

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.splitstring ( @stringToSplit VARCHAR(MAX) )
RETURNS
 @returnList TABLE ([Name] [nvarchar] (500))
AS
BEGIN

 DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @pos INT

 WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @stringToSplit) > 0
 BEGIN
  SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX(',', @stringToSplit)  
  SELECT @name = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)

  INSERT INTO @returnList 
  SELECT @name

  SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos)
 END

 INSERT INTO @returnList
 SELECT @stringToSplit

 RETURN
END
```