# SQL query to search into field with comma-separator

Tags: sql, sql-server, split, sql-server-2012

I have a table with such a structure, in SQL Server 2012 (simplified for exhibit):

```
Id  |  Val
----+----------
1   |  1, 2
2   |  1, 3
3   |  1
4   |  2, 3, 4
```

I have a stored procedure with a `@valIds` list which contains all the `Val` I'd like to request, for example `2, 3` or `3`.

In the first case, I'd like lines 1, 2 and 4 to be returned because they contains 2 **or** 3.
In the second case, I'd like lines 2 and 4 to be returned because they contains 3

Here is a fiddle to reproduce the structure : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ff399/2

I can't figure out how to split the `Val` field to search into it and get the above results. Can anyone help me ?

**Please note** : Spearator is Comma-Space, not just Comma, I'm not sure `STRING_SPLIT` can be used here

Thank you

Comment: I really suggest you fix your design. *Never* store delimited data in your database.

Comment: Sure, but this is not the point here, and this can't be changed for a bunch of reasons I can't explain here. Unfortunately, I'm not the designer of the DB and I have to deal with it

Comment: @AaronBertrand You're right, my bad, i've fixed it in my question

Comment: *"but this is not the point here"* it kind of is, I'm afraid. If you didn't have a denormalised design, you wouldn't be asking the question.

Comment: The space doesn't make STRING_SPLIT unusable, you can replace it or trim (or try to convert the values, like I did in [my now irrelevant answer](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=05c2d4d158abb5757b1a69fe45e6bc3a)). But the fact you don't use a supported version of SQL Server does make STRING_SPLIT unusable. I've adjusted the tags on your question to indicate the version; this is a much more useful place to put that information than in the text.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `LIKE` or `CHARINDEX` or `PATINDEX` to check if a value can be found in the string.

Example:

```
select *
from ACTIVITY
where concat(' ',Val,',') like concat('% ', 2,',%') 
   or charindex(' 3,', ' '+Val+',') > 0
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM ACTIVITY t
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM (VALUES (2),(3)) q(num)
  WHERE ' '+t.Val+',' like CONCAT('% ',num,',%')
);
```

Comment: CHARINDEX is definitely faster than splitting, but gets cumbersome to build (basically _requires_ dynamic SQL) if there can be more than a couple of elements in the list.

Comment: Well, since the OP is using such an old almost unsupported version, anything that works will be nice.

Comment: Ah, missed 2012 in the text. The fiddle was set to 2017.

Answer (score 1):

another option could be Charindex:

```
Declare @valIds varchar(max) = '2,3'

select distinct a.* from activity a
cross join
(Select value from String_split(@valIds,',')) as v
where charindex
(',' + value + ',' ,
 ',' + replace(val,' ','') + ',') > 0
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ff399/42

For older versions of SQL server without string_split, changed the values to table using xml:

```
Declare @valIds varchar(max) = '2,3'

;WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT 
    
      CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData>' + REPLACE(t.val,',','</RowData><RowData>') + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) AS x
      FROM (SELECT @valIds) AS t(val)
),
table_values as
(
SELECT 
    m.n.value('.[1]','varchar(8000)') value
FROM cte
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData')m(n)
)

select distinct a.* from activity a
cross join
(Select value from table_values) as v
where charindex
(',' + value + ',' ,
 ',' + replace(val,' ','') + ',') > 0
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ff399/50

csv to table credit to this answer:
[Convert comma delimited string to table or array in sql server 2008 without using dbo.split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32888266/convert-comma-delimited-string-to-table-or-array-in-sql-server-2008-without-usin#32888388)

Comment: Seems correct, thank you ! Will take a look deeper

Comment: @user2687153 Are you using SQL Server 2012? If so, `STRING_SPLIT` will not work for you. You'll [need a different function](https://sqlblog.org/split).

Comment: Missed the 2012 bit too! Added another method replacing the string_split by a csv to table using xml

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do it with "regular" XML splitting

```
DECLARE     @valIds VARCHAR(50) = '3, 4';

WITH s1 AS (
            SELECT      a.Id, b.x.value('.', 'INT') AS Val
            FROM        (
                        SELECT  *, CONVERT(XML, '<x>' + REPLACE(Val, ',', '</x><x>') + '</x>') AS XmlVal
                        FROM    Activity
                        ) a
            CROSS APPLY a.XmlVal.nodes('x') AS b(x)
            )
, s2 AS     (
            SELECT      b.x.value('.', 'INT') AS Val
            FROM        (
                        SELECT  CONVERT(XML, '<x>' + REPLACE(@valIds, ',', '</x><x>') + '</x>') AS XmlVal
                        ) a
            CROSS APPLY a.XmlVal.nodes('x') AS b(x)
            )
SELECT      *
FROM        Activity
WHERE       Id IN ( SELECT      s1.Id
                    FROM        s1
                    JOIN        s2
                    ON          s1.Val = s2.Val)
```

In `s1` column `Val` is split the way your data should have been normalized in first place.

In `s2` the parameter `@valIds` is split into integers.

Joining `s1` and `s2` on `Val` brings the `Id`s from the original `Activity` table which are matching the search terms.