# How to unlist an attribute (short to long) using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm attempting a join with a table that looks like this:

[image: Table]

I need to join on the distinct combination of SubTestCodes and TestCodes.

Is there a way to retrieve an output where the table is converted into long format (SubTestCodes becoming TestCodes)?

For this specific query there is no distinction between them.

Comment: Go and yell at the goon that put a comma delimited list of values into a single field and make them fix it?

Comment: I'm sure this question will get pounced on, and everyone will say "you shouldn't store data like this in a table". So, you shouldn't store data like this in a table...make another subcode table and a relationship between the testcode and subtestcode.

Comment: I should have mentioned I have read only access! Of course the true  solution is to reformat the data.

Comment: or...you could do a quick search and see that the question has been answered a thousand times over. Here's one to get started. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585632/how-to-convert-comma-separated-nvarchar-to-table-records-in-sql-server-2005

Comment: What version of SQL Server?  For SQL Server 2016+ you can use `STRING_SPLIT()` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql

Comment: Is it REALLY a table? Sure it's not a view?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert comma separated NVARCHAR to table records in SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585632/how-to-convert-comma-separated-nvarchar-to-table-records-in-sql-server-2005)