# How to Pass Parameter as a List In a Stored procedure in a dynamic Insert Query

Tags: sql-server

I have a scenario that @PRIVILEGEID will have multiple value and @ROLEID will be same every time for those privilege Id.

So I have to insert the data into table.
Below is the Code For Procedure:-

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ADD_ROLE] (
  @ROLENAME varchar(50),
  @PRIVILEGEID int )
AS
BEGIN

  DECLARE @QUERY varchar(1000);
  DECLARE @ROLEID int;
  SET @ROLEID = ( SELECT Max(ROLEID)
                  FROM ( SELECT
                           Max(CREATED_DATE) AS MAX_DATE,
                           ROLEID
                         FROM ROLE
                         WHERE ROLENAME = @ROLENAME
                               --(ROlename can be changed dynamically, take 'Manager' as example as of now.)     
                           AND CREATED_DATE IS NOT NULL
                         GROUP BY ROLEID ) X );
  --PRINT @ROLEID  

  SET @QUERY = 'INSERT INTO [ROLES_PRIVILEGES]  (ROLEID,PRIVILEGEID) VALUES (''' + Cast(@ROLEID AS varchar) + ''',''' + Cast(@PRIVILEGEID AS varchar) + ''')';

  EXECUTE ( @QUERY );

END;
```

Now @PRIVILEGEID will have a dynamic list of multiple values for the fixed @ROLEID and My issue is I can pass only one @PRIVILEGEID at one time.

Exec ADD_ROLE 'BACKOFFICE',@PRIVILEGEID  @PRIVILEGEID=[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

-- (How to pass multiple value for PRIVILEGEID )

I have tried While loop also but not sure how to implement it.

Please help.

Comment: Check TVP (Table value paramater) or pass comma separated value and use function to convert comma separated values to table.

Comment: How Can you help me with this..

Comment: That stored procedure doesn't need dynamic SQL. You can write an `INSER ... FROM` query to insert the results of a query into a table. The GROUP BY and `MAX(CREATED_DATE)` aren't needed either. If you want the largest RoleID for a name you can write `SELECT MAX(RoleID) from Role where RoleName=@RoleName and Created_Date IS NOT NULL)`

Comment: The entire stored procedure could contain just `INSERT INTO ROLE_PRIVILEGES (RoleID,PrivilegeID) SELECT MAX(RoleID), @PrivilegeID from Role where RoleName=@RoleName and Created_Date IS NOT NULL)`

Comment: How will i pass the multiple PRIVILEGEID. and that Privilege Id is not known to us it will be entered by some other user.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585632/how-to-convert-comma-separated-nvarchar-to-table-records-in-sql-server-2005

Comment: You can change the parameter @PRIVILEGEID to nvarchar(max) and pass the ids as comma separated string.

Comment: converting data will not help.. Exec ADD_ROLE 'BACKOFFICE',@PRIVILEGEID @PRIVILEGEID=[2, 3, 4, 5, 6] so it should enumerate the [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]  one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example where I take a comma delimited string and dump into a table. This process works by converting it into xml and using xmlqry to parse. I like it because I feel its easier to read and looks less convoluted.

Let me know if it works for you.

```
USE yourDatabase
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[_parsedelimited]
    (
        @str varchar(max)
    )
AS
BEGIN
    if object_id('tempdb..#Emails') is not null drop table #Emails;
    CREATE TABLE #Emails (Email varchar(2500));
    Declare @x XML;
    select @x = cast('<A>'+ replace(@str,',','</A><A>')+ '</A>' as xml);

    INSERT INTO #Emails (Email) 
    select 
        t.value('.', 'varchar(50)') as inVal
    from @x.nodes('/A') as x(t);

    SELECT * FROM #Emails;
    drop table #Emails;
END
GO
```

Comment: Didnt realize one of the comments in the OP was a link to an answer using the same method.

Comment: While testing the above procedure of yours exec [_SyncSendGridUnsubscribe] [A,B,C], it is giving error 'Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'A' to data type int'.

Comment: Also Can you suggest how will I integrate ur code in my procedure.

Comment: I forgot to change the data type in the xml query - sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
declare @role varchar(20) = 'BACKOFFICE', 
    @PRIVILEGEID varchar(100) = '2,3,4,5,6';

select @role, * 
from string_split(@PRIVILEGEID, ',');
```

Using that select, you should be able to insert it into whatever table you'd like.

Comment: string_split is a function?

Comment: Yes. It was added in SQL 2016: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017