# Get rows from comma separated list

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, t-sql

I want to convert a comma separated list back into a table.

For eg.

I have a table which looks like this

```
Sid  roleid
  500    1,5,
  501    1,5,6,
```

I want output like this

```
Sid roleid
500   1
500   5
501   1
501   5
501   6
```

Please help.

```
Create table #temp(Sid int,roleid varchar(100))
Insert into #temp values(500,'1,5,'),(501,'1,5,6,')
```

Comment: Tag the DBMS version that you are using.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert comma separated NVARCHAR to table records in SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585632/how-to-convert-comma-separated-nvarchar-to-table-records-in-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 2):

Using `STRING_SPLIT()` means, that you are working on SQL Server 2016 (oder higher).

However, `STRING_SPLIT()` has a huge draw back: It is not guaranteed to return the items in the expected order (see the [docs, section "Remarks"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)). In my eyes this is an absolut show stopper...

But - luckily - there is a fast and easy-to-use workaround in v2016+:

```
Create table #temp(Sid int,roleid varchar(100))
Insert into #temp values(500,'1,5,'),(501,'1,5,6,');

SELECT t.[Sid]
      ,A.[key] AS position
      ,A.[value] AS roleid
FROM #temp t
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CONCAT('["',REPLACE(t.roleid,',','","'),'"]')) A
WHERE A.[value]<>'';
```

A simple number array `1,3,5` needs nothing more than brackets to be a JSON array (`[1,3,5]`). In your case, due to the trailing comma, I deal with it as strings. `1,3,5,` will be taken as array of strings: `["1","3","5",""]`. The final empty string is taken away by the WHERE clause. The rest is easy...

Other than `STRING_SPLIT()` the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) proof, that `OPENJSON` will reflect an item's position in the `[key]` column:

> When OPENJSON parses a JSON array, the function returns the indexes of the elements in the JSON text as keys.

General hint: avoid `STRING_SPLIT()` as lons as there is no additional key/position column  added to its result set.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Use `sring_split()`:

```
select t.sid, value rid
from t
cross apply string_split(t.roleid, ',') rid
order by t.sid, rid
```

Comment: I try to avoid `STRING_SPLIT()` as long as it does not guarantee the sort order... (see my answer)

Comment: @Shnugo: in this very use case the ordering does not matter, so `string_split()` is good enough. But in general I do agree with you. `OPENJSON` is a nice alternative, upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `string_split()` :

```
select t.sid, spt.value
from table t cross apply
     string_split(t.roleid, ',') as spt
order by t.sid, spt.value;
```

Comment: I try to avoid `STRING_SPLIT()` as long as it does not guarantee the sort order... (see my answer)