# Split column value to match yes or no

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two tables named **Retail** and **Activity** and the data is as shown below:

**Retail Table**

[image]

**Activity Table**

[image]

My main concern is about **Ok and Fault** column of the table **Retail**, as you can see it contains comma separated value of **ActivityId.**

What i want is, if the **Ok** column has **ActivityId** the corresponding column will have **Yes**, if the **Fault** column has **ActivityId** then it should be marked as **No**

**Note** I have only four columns that is fixed, it means i have to check that either four of the columns has its value in **Ok or Fault**, if yes then only i have to print yes or no, otherwise null.

**Desired result should be like :**
If the value is in Ok then yes other wise No.

[image]

Comment: have you tried any query?

Comment: no yet, i am stuck and dnt know where to start :)

Comment: @HarshSharma Which RDBMS are you using? Keep proper tag of dabase and remove other tags

Comment: @SaharshShah i am using sql server 2012

Comment: @HarshSharma Please provide desired result table

Comment: What do you mean by corresponding column? Which column should have yes/no values?

Comment: @SaharshShah please check i have updated the question

Comment: first try something, then post here what errors are you facing.

Comment: What if OK and Fault both have values? Show query you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

I guessing you want to store 'yes' or 'No' in some column. Below is the query to update that column :

```
UPDATE RetailTable
 SET <Result_Column>=
  CASE 
  WHEN Ok IS NOT NULL THEN 'Yes'
  WHEN Fault IS NOT NULL THEN 'No'
  END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code as staring point:

```
DECLARE @Retail TABLE
(
PhoneAuditID INT,
HandsetQuoteID INT,
Ok VARCHAR(50)
)
INSERT INTO @Retail VALUES (1, 1009228, '4,22,5')
INSERT INTO @Retail VALUES (2, 1009229, '1')

DECLARE @Activity TABLE
(
ID INT,
Activity VARCHAR(50)
)
INSERT INTO @Activity VALUES (1, 'BatteryOK?'), (4, 'PhonePowersUp?'), (22,'SomeOtherQuestion?'), (5,'LCD works OK?')

SELECT  R.[PhoneAuditID], R.[HandsetQuoteID], A.[Activity], [Ok] = CASE WHEN A.[ID] IS NOT NULL THEN 'Yes' END
FROM    @Retail R
CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(R.Ok, ',') S
LEFT JOIN @Activity A ON S.[items] = A.[ID]
```

I have used Split function provided here:
[separate comma separated values and store in table in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811316/separate-comma-separated-values-and-store-in-table-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

Try following query. i have used pivot to show row as columns. I have also used split function to split id values which you can find easily on net:

```
CREATE TABLE PhoneAudit
(
    PhoneAuditRetailID INT,
    HandsetQuoteID INT,
    Ok VARCHAR(50),
    Fault VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO PhoneAudit VALUES (1,10090,'1,2','3')

CREATE TABLE ActivityT
(
    ID INT,
    Activity VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO ActivityT VALUES (1,'Battery')
INSERT INTO ActivityT VALUES (2,'HasCharger')
INSERT INTO ActivityT VALUES (3,'HasMemoryCard')
INSERT INTO ActivityT VALUES (4,'Test')

DECLARE @SQL AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') + QUOTENAME(Activity) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Activity FROM ActivityT) AS Activities

SET @SQL = 'SELECT PhoneAuditRetailID, HandsetQuoteID,
  ' + @ColumnName + '
FROM
(SELECT
    t1.PhoneAuditRetailID,
    t1.HandsetQuoteID,
    TEMPOK.*
FROM
    PhoneAudit t1
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT
        Activity,
        (CASE WHEN ID IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.SplitIDs(t1.Ok,'','')) 
        THEN ''YES'' 
        ELSE ''NO''
        END) AS VALUE
    FROM
        ActivityT t2
) AS TEMPOK) AS t3
PIVOT
(
    MIN(VALUE)
    FOR Activity IN ('+ @ColumnName + ')
) AS PivotTable;'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL

DROP TABLE PhoneAudit
DROP TABLE ActivityT
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this.  If you are looking for a purely declarative approach, you could use a recursive CTE.  The following example of this is presented as a generic solution with test data which should be adaptable to your needs:

```
Declare @Delimiter As Varchar(2)

Set @Delimiter = ','

Declare @Strings As Table
(
    String Varchar(50)
)

Insert Into @Strings
Values
    ('12,345,6,78,9'),
    (Null),
    (''),
    ('123')

;With String_Columns As
(
    Select
       String,
       Case
          When String Is Null Then ''
          When CharIndex(@Delimiter,String,0) = 0 Then ''
          When Len(String) = 0 Then ''
          Else Left(String,CharIndex(@Delimiter,String,0)-1)
       End As String_Column,
       Case
          When String Is Null Then ''
          When CharIndex(@Delimiter,String,0) = 0 Then ''
          When Len(String) = 0 Then ''
          When Len(Left(String,CharIndex(@Delimiter,String,0)-1)) = 0 Then ''
          Else Right(String,Len(String)-Len(Left(String,CharIndex(@Delimiter,String,0)-1))-1)
       End As Remainder,
       1 As String_Column_Number
    From
       @Strings
    Union All
    Select
       String,
       Case
          When CharIndex(@Delimiter,Remainder,0) = 0 Then Remainder
          Else Left(Remainder,CharIndex(@Delimiter,Remainder,0)-1)
       End As Remainder,
       Case
          When CharIndex(@Delimiter,Remainder,0) = 0 Then ''
          When Len(Left(Remainder,CharIndex(@Delimiter,Remainder,0)-1)) = 0 Then ''
          Else Right(Remainder,Len(Remainder)-Len(Left(Remainder,CharIndex(@Delimiter,Remainder,0)-1))-1)
       End As Remainder,
       String_Column_Number + 1
    From
       String_Columns
    Where
       (Remainder Is Not Null And Len(Remainder) > 1)
)
Select
    String,
    String_Column,
    String_Column_Number
From
    String_Columns
```