# how to insert values of a column of a table dynamically

Tags: .net, sql-server, model-view-controller

How to pass an array to `SQL SERVER 2008` stored procedure and insert all the values of a array into a database table.

For Example: From `ASP.NET mvc C#`, I would pass a parameter having multiple values separated by comma

as below

```
string category = "Cat1, Cat2, Cat3, Cat4";
```

I would like to insert all the values of above string in a table called Categories.

How could I achieve this using `SQL SERVER 2008`.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811316/separate-comma-separated-values-and-store-in-table-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it easily by converting `CSV` values to `XML` format and then use `CROSS APPLY` on it to split it to rows and insert it your table.

```
CREATE TABLE #Categories(VALUE VARCHAR(100))

DECLARE @STR VARCHAR(500)='Cat1, Cat2, Cat3, Cat4'

INSERT INTO #Categories(VALUE)
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'))) 'VALUE' 
FROM  
(
     -- To change ',' to any other delimeter, just change ',' before '</M><M>' to your desired one
     SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(@STR, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data             
) AS A 
CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)

SELECT * FROM #Categories
```

- **[Click here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/280855/split-csv-to-rows) to view result**