# how to split one row to many based on a comma separate column

Tags: mysql, sql

here is my data in mysql table:

```
name    childid
city    11,12,13
maintain    21,22,29
pool    33,39,100
```

I want to get data as the below format. So I can use it to join another tables.

```
11    city
12    city
13    city
21    maintain
22    maintain
29    maintain
33    pool
39    pool
100   pool
```

Comment: I would run jdbc/pdo/whatever query "select * from table", use explode() function and loop/insert it in a new table.

Comment: And never store data like that again!

Comment: While you probably _can_ do it in MySQL, I'd suggest to do it in Python/Ruby/PHP or whatever your server script language is.

Comment: don't ask similar type of questions these are already present in stackoverflow please surf folks.....here is link ..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811316/separate-comma-separated-values-and-store-in-table-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very bad format, as no doubt comments and other answers will tell you.  You want a junction table -- and this is perhaps why you want this query.

The simplest way is if you have a table of all valid child ids.  Then you can do:

```
select c.id, d.name
from mydata d join
     children c
     on find_in_set(c.id, childid) > 0;
```