# T-SQL How can I use a variable in the WHERE IN clause?

Tags: sql-server

I can do this and it works (but would like something more simple):

```
Declare @PropIDs        varchar(50)
Set @PropIDs = '1, 2'

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.TempProp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.TempProp

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TempProp](
    [PropCode] [VarChar](3) NULL)

Set @Sql = 'Insert Into TempProp Select PropertyCode From Property where PropertyID In (' + @PropIDs + ')'

Execute (@Sql)
```

But I wish I could do just this:

```
Declare @PropIDs
Set @PropIDs = '1, 2'
Select PropertyCode 
Into #TempProp
From Property where PropertyID IN (@PropIDs)
```

It is the "...Property IN (@PropIDs)" that is giving me trouble.
Any suggestions?

Comment: If your values are in a list like that, then you have to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: I meant "...PropertyID IN (@PropIDs)" part that is giving me trouble

Comment: Use a table-valued parameter instead of a comma-separated string. This isn't JSON, those are individual values.

Answer (score 0):

Create a split table value function similar to this one

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[Split](@String varchar(MAX), @Delimiter char(1))       
returns @temptable TABLE (items varchar(MAX))       
as       
begin      
    declare @idx int       
    declare @slice varchar(8000)       

    select @idx = 1       
        if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return       

    while @idx!= 0       
    begin       
        set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)       
        if @idx!=0       
            set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)       
        else       
            set @slice = @String       

        if(len(@slice)>0)  
            insert into @temptable(Items) values(@slice)       

        set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)       
        if len(@String) = 0 break       
    end   
return 
end;
```

That code is from this question: [separate comma separated values and store in table in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811316/separate-comma-separated-values-and-store-in-table-in-sql-server)

Then use it in your query like this:

```
Declare @PropIDs
Set @PropIDs = '1, 2'
Select PropertyCode 
Into #TempProp
From Property where PropertyID IN (dbo.Slit(@PropIDs, ','))
```