# Query for match all records in list SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table bawe_services. i want to fetch all data that match with given keys

like i have fields

```
id  | Service_id |bawe_id
1       2          2
2       3          3
3       2          3
```

if i pass service =2 i need all record of service_id=2 if i pass service=1,2,3 than i want 0 rows because 1 service is not given by any bawe so. i got 0 rows.

I use this query

```
select * from aspnet_bawe_services where ser_id in(1,2,3)
```

Thanx in advance

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: How many rows you except at service=2 and which columns of the table you need? Best if you do samples incl. the expected output.

Comment: I think OP wants to display all the matching rows but `service_id` must be exist for all service ids that we provide. If we provide `2,3` then it should return all from the given table, when `1,2,3` or `2,3,4` then no any rows because `1` or `4` not exist in the `service_id` column.

Comment: I'm asking for columns because it is more easy to return only bawe_id and not the full table (or the rowid).

Comment: yes exactly ...

Comment: yes you can return bawe_id @BerndOtt

Comment: @Pankaj, I have posted dynamic solution of your requirement so please try it once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The count of the parameters in the "in" statement must match the having equal number.

```
select bawe_id from [dbo].[aspnet_bawe_services]
where Service_id in (2)
group by bawe_id
having count(Service_id)=1;

bawe_id
-----------
2
3

select bawe_id from [dbo].[aspnet_bawe_services]
where Service_id in (2,3)
group by bawe_id
having count(Service_id)=2;

bawe_id
-----------
3

select bawe_id from [dbo].[aspnet_bawe_services]
where Service_id in (1,2,3)
group by bawe_id
having count(Service_id)=3;

bawe_id
-----------

(0 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Thanx @Bernd Ott for clear specification. this one help me hope it will help other developer also. appreciate your efforts +1.

Answer (score 1):

**TRY THIS**: It's really tedious but unique requirement and I think to accomplish this, we have to use function

1-Function returns distinct count of service_id

2-Function to split comma separated value and return in table format

--Function returns distinct count of service_id

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[getCount](@service_id varchar(500))
RETURNS INT             
AS       
BEGIN   
    DECLARE @count int   

    SELECT @count = COUNT(DISTINCT(t.service_id))
    FROM tmptos t
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[SplitValue](@service_id, ',') tt on t.service_id = tt.items

RETURN @count
END;
```

--Function to split comma separated value and return in table format
--Function copied from 
--[separate comma separated values and store in table in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811316/separate-comma-separated-values-and-store-in-table-in-sql-server)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitValue](@String varchar(MAX), @Delimiter char(1))       
RETURNS @temptable TABLE (items VARCHAR(MAX))       
AS       
BEGIN      
    DECLARE @idx int       
    DECLARE @slice varchar(8000)       

    SELECT @idx = 1       
        if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return       

    WHILE @idx!= 0       
    BEGIN       
        set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)       
        IF @idx!=0       
            set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)       
        else       
            set @slice = @String       

        IF(LEN(@slice)>0)  
            INSERT INTO @temptable(Items) values(@slice)       

        SET @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)       
        IF LEN(@String) = 0 break       
    END   
RETURN 
END;

--Table with Sample Data

create table tmptos(id int, Service_id int, bawe_id int)
insert into tmptos values
(1,       2,          2),
(2,       3,         3),
(3,       2,          3)


declare @service_id varchar(50) = '2,3'

select *
from tmptos t
inner join [dbo].[SplitValue](@service_id, ',') tt on t.Service_id = tt.items
where [dbo].[getCount](@service_id) = (select count(distinct(items)) from [dbo].[SplitValue](@service_id, ','))
```

OUTPUT:

```
id  Service_id  bawe_id items
1   2           2       2
2   3           3       3
3   2           3       2
```

It's bit lengthy but works perfectly.

Comment: Appreciate you work i voted on your hard work but  @Bernd Ott's answer worked for me and i think that  is simple aslo.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from aspnet_bawe_services 
where Service_id  in (1,2,3) 
and 
( select count(distinct Service_id) from aspnet_bawe_services where Service_id  in (1,2,3) ) = 3
```

last number in query (in this case "3")  is elements count, which you have in `IN` list.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the service ids that you want using `group by` and `having`:

```
select service_id
from t
where bawe_id in (1, 2, 3)
group by service_id
having count(distinct bawe_id) = 3;
```

The "= 3" is the number of ids in the `IN` list.

You can then use `in` or `join` or `exists` to get the full records:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.service_id in (select service_id
                       from t
                       where bawe_id in (1, 2, 3)
                       group by service_id
                       having count(distinct bawe_id) = 3
                      );
```

Comment: Do we have to make changes in `having count(distinct bawe_id) = 3` when provided service ids are exactly not equal to `3` or I mean `1,2 or more than that` ?