# How to Group data with join from other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

Stores=>  id,zip_id,stores

Zips => id,zip_code,county,state

the column store in store table is comma separated values , how can i get all the stores states wise.

Comment: Could you please add snapshot of both tables and expected output

Answer (score 0):

See if these threads can help,

1. [separate comma separated values and store in table in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811316/separate-comma-separated-values-and-store-in-table-in-sql-server)
2. [Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows)