# Best way to replace IN clause with LIKE or something equivalent

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-like

I have existing SQL like the following (this is a contrived example):

```
DECLARE @Var NVARCHAR(256)

SELECT @Var = SomeValue
FROM SomeTable

SELECT *
FROM AnotherTable B
WHERE @Var IN ('One','Two','Three')
   OR (@Var IN ('Four','Five') AND [Some Other Condition])
```

This works great when @Var is equal to a single value like 'Two'. But now the specs have changed and @Var can now be equal to a comma delimited string like 'Two,Four'.  What's the best way to change the above code to support that?

The obvious/brute-force way is to change it to use multiple LIKEs:

```
SELECT *
FROM AnotherTable B
WHERE (@Var LIKE '%One%' OR @Var LIKE '%Two%' OR @Var LIKE '%Three%')
  OR ((@Var LIKE '%Four%' OR @Var LIKE '%Five%')) AND [Some Other Condition])
```

But is there a better way?

I was hoping SQL Server had support for regular expressions, but sadly it's very limited and as far as I can tell doesn't support searching for multiple words.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use string_split function perhaps to split the string into keywords

Comment: Switch to a table type parameter, rather than a delimited list?

Comment: The "obvious" way is to use a table type parameter - we are talking data here, so tables are the order of the day, not string comparison.

Comment: Will using a table type parameter or string_split have better or worse performance than doing string comparison with LIKE?  The example I provided is contrived, but imagine the WHERE clause has many more conditions that need to compare @Var with different lists of values.  I just don't know if doing a subquery of a temp table (or table variable) for every comparison is preferred over string LIKE comparison.

Comment: So you'll never have to deal with `'%One%'` matching `'Tone'`? Playing with matching bits of substring often goes awry. You can go with the traditional `',' + @Var + ',' like '%,One,%'` to ensure that the target is delimited, but that gets rather clumsy and is somewhat error prone when maintaining the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am with siggemannen.

[separate comma separated values and store in table in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811316/separate-comma-separated-values-and-store-in-table-in-sql-server)

Below uses the function from that answer.

```
declare @var nvarchar(max) = 'one,two';

SELECT
    *
INTO #tmp_passed_variables
FROM [dbo].[Split](@var, ',') 

select * from #tmp_passed_variables
```

Results

| items |
| --- |
| one |
| two |

```
SELECT
    *
INTO #tmp_AnotherTable
FROM(
    VALUES ('data1'),('data2')
) x (id)

SELECT *
FROM #tmp_AnotherTable B
WHERE (SELECT 1 FROM #tmp_passed_variables var WHERE var.items in('five') ) = 1

SELECT *
FROM #tmp_AnotherTable B
WHERE (SELECT 1 FROM #tmp_passed_variables var WHERE var.items in('one') ) = 1
```

Query 1 no results

Query 2 has results

| id |
| --- |
| data1 |
| data2 |

You should be able to work everything as needed to fit your end needs. You can also use it as a join or to set variable flags, etc...

Comment: Thanks, I wound up with a similar solution using a tmp table, but using BIT vars for core conditions that are calc'd by querying the tmp table, then using those vars in the main query: DECLARE IsOneTwoThree BIT = 0, IsFourFive BIT = 0; SELECT IsOneTwoThree = 1 FROM #Tmp WHERE Val IN ('One','Two','Three'); SELECT IsFourFive = 1 FROM #Tmp WHERE Val IN ('Four','Five');  And finally SELECT * FROM AnotherTable WHERE IsOneTwoThree = 1 OR (IsFourFive = 1 AND [AnotherCondtion]).  It works well for me because there's only a handful of core conditions, but they are used in a lot of places.