# Insert Comma seperated varchar into multiple column value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have varchar string value like this

`"AccountType","contains","Customer","Balance","equals",250,"FirstName","like","John"`

Now I want to insert this

In a table like this

```
  FieldName       FieldContiion  FieldValue

  AccountType     contains       Customer
  Balance         equals         250
  FirstName       like           John
```

The length of the string variable can be change like this

`"Balance","equals",250,"FirstName","like","John"`
it means that it will insert just two rows in table.

Comment: Sorry @ling.s in my case there is three fields in a table and I can't take a constant value.

Comment: Create a stored procedure to use the following to break the string up and insert into your table.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/702968/how-do-i-expand-comma-separated-values-into-separate-rows-using-sql-server-2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following steps:

1) Create a split function for your comma separated string:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split] (
    @InputString                  VARCHAR(8000),
    @Delimiter                    VARCHAR(50)
)

RETURNS @Items TABLE (
    Item                          VARCHAR(8000)
)

AS
BEGIN
    IF @Delimiter = ' '
    BEGIN
          SET @Delimiter = ','
          SET @InputString = REPLACE(@InputString, ' ', @Delimiter)
    END

    IF (@Delimiter IS NULL OR @Delimiter = '')
        SET @Delimiter = ','

    DECLARE @Item                 VARCHAR(8000)
    DECLARE @ItemList       VARCHAR(8000)
    DECLARE @DelimIndex     INT

    SET @ItemList = @InputString
    SET @DelimIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @ItemList, 0)
    WHILE (@DelimIndex != 0)
    BEGIN
          SET @Item = SUBSTRING(@ItemList, 0, @DelimIndex)
          INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@Item)

          SET @ItemList = SUBSTRING(@ItemList, @DelimIndex+1, LEN(@ItemList)-@DelimIndex)
          SET @DelimIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @ItemList, 0)
    END

    IF @Item IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
          SET @Item = @ItemList
          INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@Item)
    END

    ELSE INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@InputString)

    RETURN

END
```

2) Create a procedure that receives as parameter the comma separated string. In this example I'm using your fixed string but you should modify this to make it work with a parameter.
Note: I'm taking in consideration that your destination table has always 3 columns and that the comma separated string has a length of a multiple of 3 always... You must adapt the procedure if this change...

```
/* Get the length of the comma separated string */
DECLARE @ITEM_COUNT INT

SELECT @ITEM_COUNT = COUNT(*) FROM
(
    SELECT  item
        FROM Split('"AccountType","contains","Customer","Balance","equals",250,"FirstName","like","John"',',')  
) N

declare @x int
set @x = 1

/* Insert in your table every 3 columns... */
WHILE (@x < @ITEM_COUNT)
BEGIN 

    insert into test 
    select /* pivoting the sub-query */
      fieldname = max(case when seq = @x then item end),
      fieldcondition = max(case when seq = @x + 1 then item end),
      fieldvalue = max(case when seq = @x + 2 then item end)
    from 
    (
        SELECT  item
               ,row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS seq 
                FROM Split('"AccountType","contains","Customer","Balance","equals",250,"FirstName","like","John"',',')  
    ) a

set @x = @x + 3

END
```

Hope this helps

Comment: But one thing give a problem here. The output is not come in sequence. For example when i put
"AccountName","contains","ort","AccountType","contains","Customer"

The result is not in sequence

"AccountName" "AccountType" "contains"
"contains" "Customer" "ort"

Comment: Yes, I've made a mistake when I ordered the resultset of the inner query. The solution is just to ignore the ORDER BY clause using "SELECT 1". I have updated it

Answer (score 0):

Split the string over the delimiter (`,` in your case) and then iterate over the array of substrings and insert into the table. Your code would be something like the following :

```
array subStrings[] = string.split(",");
int i=0;
while(i<len(subStrings)){
    // create query using the ith, (i+1)th and (i+2)th elements of the array
i=i+3;
}
```

One assumption in the above code is that the main string would have elements in multiples of 3 only.