# How to split single cell into multiple columns in sql server 2008R2?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to split each name for individual columns

```
create table split_test(value integer,Allnames varchar(40))
insert into split_test values(1,'Vinoth,Kumar,Raja,Manoj,Jamal,Bala');
select * from split_test;

Value   Allnames
-------------------
1       Vinoth,Kumar,Raja,Manoj,Jamal,Bala
```

**Expected output**

```
values  N1     N2     N3      N4    N5      N6    N7.......N20
1      Vinoth  Kumar  Raja   Manoj  Jamal   Bala
```

Comment: This is a very, very bad design. Please normalize your table.

Comment: Search google for : sql server convert csv to rows. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/732596/Converting-comma-separated-data-in-a-column-to-row

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I expand comma separated values into separate rows using SQL Server 2005?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/702968/how-do-i-expand-comma-separated-values-into-separate-rows-using-sql-server-2005)

Comment: Unless you have an upper bound of max splits, you need dynamic SQL.  And this is a _terrible_ design (the fact that you're trying to split it into actual columns should have been your first clue).

Answer (score 0):

using this example you can get an idea.

```
declare @str varchar(max)
set @str = 'Hello world'

declare @separator varchar(max)
set @separator = ' '

declare @Splited table(id int identity(1,1), item varchar(max))

set @str = REPLACE(@str,@separator,'''),(''')

set @str = 'select * from (values('''+@str+''')) as V(A)' 

insert into @Splited
exec(@str)
select * from @Splited
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an sql statement using recursive CTE to split names into rows, then pivot rows into columns.
<kbd>[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c3d94/26)</kbd>

```
with names as
(select 
  value,
  1 as name_id,
    substring(Allnames,1,charindex(',',Allnames+',', 0)-1)  as name,
    substring(Allnames,charindex(',',Allnames, 0)+1, 40) as left_names
from split_test
union all
select 
  value,
  name_id +1,
  case when charindex(',',left_names, 0)> 0 then
    substring(left_names,1,charindex(',',left_names, 0)-1) 
  else left_names end as name,
  case when charindex(',',left_names, 0)> 0 then
    substring(left_names,charindex(',',left_names, 0)+1, 40) 
  else '' end as left_names
from names
where ltrim(left_names)<>'')
select value,
  [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9]
from (select value,name_id,name from names) as t1
PIVOT (MAX(name) FOR name_id IN ( [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9] ) ) AS t2
```

**UPDATE**

**[@KM.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/703125/3630826)** might be a better way to split data into rows without recursive CTE table. It should be more efficient than this one. So I follow that example and simplified the part of null value process logic. Here is the result:

**Step 1:** 
 Create a table includes all numbers from 1 to a number grater than max length of `Allnames` column.

```
CREATE TABLE Numbers( Number  int   not null primary key);
with n as
(select 1 as num
union all
select num +1
from n
where num<100)
insert into numbers
select num from n;
```

**Step 2:** 
Join data of split_test table with numbers table, we can get all the parts start from `,`. 
Then take the first part between 2 `,` form every row. If there are null values exists, add them with union.

```
select value , 
 ltrim(rtrim(substring(allnames,number+1,charindex(',',substring(allnames,number,40),2)-2))) as name
from
 (select value, ','+allnames+',' as allnames
  from split_test) as t1
left join numbers
on number<= len(allnames)
where substring(allnames,number,1)=',' 
 and substring(allnames,number,40)<>','
union
select value, Allnames
from split_test
where Allnames is null
```

**Step 3:** Pivot names from rows to columns like my first attempt above, omitted here.
<kbd>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/19b6c/5)</kbd>

Comment: If you look around the question, you can find the number of values are not fixed (N1, N2...), so you can't decide it up to 6 levels. It may be more or less...