# How to extract and split IDs from nvarchar column surrounded by spaces and a slash to compare to other table's value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I feel my problem is very complicated.
I have a Table A with a column named AbsenceLinks. 

The table would look like this:

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

|     **Description**     |    **AbsenceLinks**  |
|- - - - - - - - - - - - - + - - - - - - - - - - - - - -|
|         Illness          |        14/3 15/9       
|
|- - - - - - - - - - - - - + - - - - - - - - - - - - - -| 

|     Education        |        19/3 18/9       
|
|- - - - - - - - - - - - - + - - - - - - - - - - - - - -| 

|Leave of Absence|            20/3            
|
|- - - - - - - - - - - - - + - - - - - - - - - - - - - -| 

|      Holiday           |             8/3            
|
l- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -l

I have another table B where I have a column named AbsenceID that matches the number before the slash-symbol in the AbsenceLinks column.
(Table A AbsenceLinks value '20/9' matches AbsenceID 20 in table B)

This table would look like this:

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

|          **Absence**           |       **AbsenceID**     
|
| - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -+ - - - - - - - - - - - - - -|
|        Illness (Days)      |             14               
|
| - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -+ - - - - - - - - - - - - - -|

|            Illness             |              15             
|
| - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -+ - - - - - - - - - - - - - -|

|    Leave of Absence   |             20             
|
| - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -+ - - - - - - - - - - - - - -|
|Holiday Without Salary|              8             
|
l- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -l

I tried to see how I could retrieve some of the string from AbsenceLinks and made a case statement:

```
CASE
WHEN LEN(AbsenceLink) = 3 THEN SUBSTRING(AbsenceLink,1,1) --1/3
WHEN LEN(AbsenceLink) = 4 and SUBSTRING(AbsenceLink,1,4) LIKE '%/' THEN SUBSTRING(AbsenceLink,1,1)--1/10
WHEN LEN(AbsenceLink) = 4 AND SUBSTRING(AbsenceLink,1,4) LIKE '%/%' THEN SUBSTRING(AbsenceLink,1,2)--17/3
WHEN LEN(AbsenceLink) = 8 AND SUBSTRING(AbsenceLink,1,2) like '%/' AND SUBSTRING(AbsenceLink,5,2) like '%/' THEN SUBSTRING(AbsenceLink,1,1)+', '+SUBSTRING(AbsenceLink,5,1)--2/9 1/10
WHEN LEN(AbsenceLink) = 8 AND SUBSTRING(AbsenceLink,1,3) like '%/' AND SUBSTRING(AbsenceLink,5,3) like '%/' THEN SUBSTRING(AbsenceLink,1,2)+', '+SUBSTRING(AbsenceLink,5,2)--10/3 9/9
WHEN lenLENAbsenceLink) = 9 AND SUBSTRING(AbsenceLink,1,3) like '%/' AND SUBSTRING(AbsenceLink,5,4) like '%' THEN SUBSTRING(AbsenceLink,1,2)+', '+SUBSTRING(AbsenceLink,5,3)--14/3 15/9
End AS AbsLink
```

I have to compare theese values in a report for some statistic for a customer.
**I need theese two tables to be linked and theese columns are the only columns which can be linked**.

I want to do like this:

```
SELECT A.col1, A.col2, B.col1, B.col2
FROM TableA A, TableB B
WHERE A.AbsenceLink = B.Absence
```

### The problem is:

- The value of AbsenceLink is a nvarchar value like '20 / 3 1/9 ', there may be one or many spaces before or after the AbsenceID
- Absence is a int value like 20 and 1.
- I want 20 and 1 from '20/3 1/9' to be compared and linked with the Absence value.
- It is a database at my work and I can't change the data or make another table.

**So dearest wise and clever programmers - what can I do?**

Comment: Suggest you get rid of those `&nbsp;`s with four spaces ahead instead. And post your expecting result on please.

Comment: Thank you.
I'm not expecting a result as such. 
I just want to do like this: 

SELECT A.col1, A.col2, B.col2, B.col2 
FROM TableA A, B TableB 
WHERE A.AbsenceLink = B.Absence 

But the value of AbsenceLink is a nvarchar value like '20 / 3 1/9 'and Absence is a int value like 20 and 1.

I want 20 and one from '20 / 3 1/9 "to be compared and linked with the Absence value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from Jaugar Chang I found out the solution to my problem. The code below will show the following result:

**______________________________**
|  **Description**           |    **AbsenceLinks**  |
|- - - - - - - - - - - - - - +  -  - - - - - - - - - - - |
|  Education               |    19                      |
|- - - - - - - - - - - - - - + - - - - - - - - - - - - |
|  Education               |    18                      |
|- - - - - - - - - - - - - - + - - - - - - - - - - - - |
|  Holiday                   |    8                        |
|- - - - - - - - - - - - - - + - - - - - - - - - - - - |
| Illness                     |    14                      |
|- - - - - - - - - - - - - - + - - - - - - - - - - - - |
| Illness                     |        15                      |
|- - - - - - - - - - - - - - + - - - - - - - - - - - - |
|
Leave of Absence  |    20                      |
|**______________________________**|

```
WITH links AS
(

SELECT 
    Description,
    SUBSTRING(AbsenceLink,0,CHARINDEX('/',AbsenceLink, 0)) AS AbsenceID,
    CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',AbsenceLink, 0) > 0 
        THEN SUBSTRING(AbsenceLink,CHARINDEX(' ',AbsenceLink, 0)+1,255) 
        ELSE '' 
        END AS linkAbsNr
FROM TableA

UNION ALL

SELECT 
       Description,
       SUBSTRING(linkAbsNr,0,CHARINDEX('/',linkAbsNr, 0)) AS AbsenceID,
       CASE 
           WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',linkAbsNr, 0) > 0 
           THEN SUBSTRING(linkAbsNr,CHARINDEX(' ',linkAbsNr, 0)+1,255)
       ELSE '' 
       END AS RightAbsNr
FROM links
where linkAbsNr <> ''
)

SELECT  Description, AbsenceID 
FROM links
ORDER BY Description
```

Comment: Did you try the non-recursion way? It may speeding up your performance a lot. Worth to try it with your real data.

Answer (score 2):

### UPDATE: Method with substring and join only.

There is a similar question [expand-comma-separated-values-into-separate-rows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/703125/3630826) answered by @KM. we could reference.

Your case is a little different from that one. You should take all the parts within some  spaces before and a slash after. It's little harder than split string from a single character. But you can divide it into several steps to solve it.

- **Extract every part stopped by '/' into rows**

  - The method of @KM. works well of doing this.
- **Take the last part with spaces ahead.**

  - There may have spaces before the last '/', we need to find the position of the last space after trim the spaces before the last '/'. So we use the trick of revers like this `charindex(' ', reverse(rtrim(left(AbsenceLink,number-1))),0)`.

Here is the result:<kbd>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/89cfbe/11)</kbd>

```
with numbers as
(select 1 as number
union all
select number +1
from numbers
where number<100)
select 
 Description , 
 right(rtrim(left(AbsenceLink,number-1)),charindex(' ', reverse(rtrim(left(AbsenceLink,number-1))),0)) as AbsenceID
from
 (select Description, ' '+AbsenceLink as AbsenceLink
  from t) as t1
left join numbers
on number<= len(AbsenceLink)
where substring(AbsenceLink,number,1)='/'
```

**NOTE:**

- If you care about the performance, create an permanent `numbers` table instead of temp table may be helpful.
- More specific explain in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25624014/3630826).

### Method with CTE recursive query

<kbd>[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9b1ed/3)</kbd>

```
with links as
(select 
  Description,
  substring(AbsenceLink,1,charindex('/',AbsenceLink, 0)-1) as AbsenceID,
  case when 
    charindex(' ',AbsenceLink, 0) > 0 then
    substring(AbsenceLink,charindex(' ',AbsenceLink, 0)+1,255)
  else '' end as left_links
from (select convert(varchar(255),ltrim(rtrim(substring(AbsenceLink,1,charindex('/',AbsenceLink, 0)-1) )) + '/' +ltrim(substring(AbsenceLink,charindex('/',AbsenceLink, 0)+1, 255) ) )as AbsenceLink,
             Description 
      from t) as t1
union all
select 
  Description,
  substring(left_links,1,charindex('/',left_links, 0)-1) as AbsenceID,
  case when 
    charindex(' ',left_links, 0) > 0 then
    substring(left_links,charindex(' ',left_links, 0)+1,255)
  else '' end as left_links
from (select convert(varchar(255),ltrim(rtrim(substring(left_links,1,charindex('/',left_links, 0)-1) )) + '/' +ltrim(substring(left_links,charindex('/',left_links, 0)+1, 255) ) )as left_links,
             Description             
      from links
      where left_links<>'') as t2
)
select 
 * from links
order by Description
```

- With recursive CTE table, to get first link's absence id in every iteration until all links processed.
- If there are more than one space before or after `/`, `ltrim(rtrim(substring(AbsenceLink,1,charindex('/',AbsenceLink, 0)-1) )) + '/' + ltrim(substring(AbsenceLink,charindex('/',AbsenceLink, 0)+1, 255) )` can get rid off all the spaces before or after the first `/` in each recursive step.
- To convert varchar to integer, can reference to [SqlServer document here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) about convert function.

Two methods can get the same result like this:

```
DESCRIPTION   ABSENCEID 
Illness              14 
Illness              15 
Education            18 
Education            19 
Holiday               8 
Leave of Absence     20
```

Answer (score 0):

you can retrieve id with this query :

```
SELECT(SUBSTRING(AbsenceLink,0,CHARINDEX('/', AbsenceLink))) FROM table_name
```

and do your work

Comment: That was a good one, but as a result, I'm missing the last number. Example: '14/3 15/9' this will only show number 14, it should also show number 15.
I will figure it out with your   solution.

Answer (score 0):

OK dude, with this function you can split your field value and get the `id`

```
CREATE FUNCTION return_id(@Str VARCHAR(10), @part INT)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @part1 VARCHAR(10),
            @part2 VARCHAR(10)

    DECLARE @Spc_Indx     INT,
            @retVal       INT

    SET @retVal = 0
    SET @part1 = @Str
    SET @part2 = ''

    IF CHARINDEX(' ', @Str) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @Spc_Indx = CHARINDEX(' ', @Str)
        SELECT @part1 = SUBSTRING(@str, 0, @Spc_Indx),
               @part2 = SUBSTRING(@Str, @Spc_Indx + 1, LEN(@str) -@Spc_Indx)
    END

    IF @part = 1
        SET @retVal = CAST(SUBSTRING(@part1, 0, CHARINDEX('/', @part1)) AS INT)

    IF @part = 2
        SET @retVal = CAST(SUBSTRING(@part2, 0, CHARINDEX('/', @part2)) AS INT)

    RETURN @retVal
END
```

and you should to use this in your query :

```
SELECT return_id(AbsenceLink,1),return_id(AbsenceLink,2) FROM table_name
```