# how to get a string from a list of string using SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have table tableA as below:

```
+--------+----------------------+
|   Id   |          Ref         |
+--------+----------------------+
|    1   |    RN1-102,RN2-103   |  
|    2   |    RN1-106           |
|    3   |    RN2-203           |
|    4   |    NULL              |
|    5   |    RN1-104|,RN2-107  |
|    6   |    RN1-101,RN2-105   |
|    7   |    RN1-100,RN2-109   |
+--------+----------------------+
```

I need a output (distinct Ref from tableA) as below:

```
+--------------------+
| Distinct Ref data  |
+--------------------+
|      RN1-100       |
|      RN1-101       |
|      RN1-102       |
|      RN1-104       |
|      RN1-106       |
|      RN2-103       |
|      RN2-105       |
|      RN7-107       |
|      RN2-109       |
|      RN2-203       |
+--------------------+
```

I tried with below query:

```
select distinct Ref from tableA
```

Please help me out..

Comment: the schema is a bad practice I think. but try to check this out, it had the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308669/reverse-group-concat-in-mysql

Comment: The table u have provided is not a good practice(multiple values in one row).Try to change the schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this

```
SELECT distinct Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') REF
           FROM   (select ID,Cast ('<M>'
                                + replace(Replace(REF, ',', '</M><M>'),'&','&amp;')
                                + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data from #Table) AS A
                  CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25624014/3630826) I answered before. I offered two approach in that answer, one is using recursive another not.

But if you already have a table stores the `ref` keys, you have the third choice like this:

```
create table ref_table (ref varchar(10), ref_name varchar(100), primary key (ref));

select
    r.ref
from 
    ref_table r
where 
    EXISTS (
        select 1 
        from tableA a
        where a.ref like '%'+r.ref+'%'  -- or ','+a.ref+',' like '%,'+r.ref+',%' 
        )
```

<kbd>[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/60d2c/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') REF
           FROM   (select ID,Cast ('<M>'
                                + replace(Replace(REF, ',', '</M><M>'),'&','&amp;')
                                + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data from #Table) AS A
                  CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
```