# SQL Server 2008 R2: Assign alias dynamically

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following string to make it as expected.

**Given String**:

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(MAX) = '[ColumnA],[ColumnB],[ColumnC]'
                              /*Will be any numbers of columns*/
```

**Expected String**:

```
SUM([ColumnA]) AS [ColumnA],SUM([ColumnB]) AS [ColumnA],SUM([ColumnC]) AS [ColumnA]
```

## My TRY:

```
SELECT 'SUM('+ REPLACE(@String,',','),SUM(') + ')'
```

I am just able to get:

```
SUM([ColumnA]),SUM([ColumnB]),SUM([ColumnC])
```

Got stuck to assign the alias infront of each sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd used one of [split functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702968/how-do-i-expand-comma-separated-values-into-separate-rows-using-sql-server-2005) and `FOR XML`.

```
    SELECT STUFF(
                   (select ', SUM('+sit.items +') AS '+sit.items
                    from dbo.uf_SplitIntoTableStr('[column1],[column2]',',') sit
                    for xml path('')
                 ),1,1,'')
```